# linux find file in directory with given string in content

Tags: linux, grep, find

In Linux (command line):

I need to find all Perl-files (filename ends with `.pl` or `.pm`) that are located in `/users/tom/` or any of its sub-directories and which contain both the string `->get(` and the string `#hyphenate` (located in different lines or in the same line). I just need the names of the files (and their path's). I don't need the lines within the file where the strings was found.

Is there a command that can do this?

I know how to find files with one extension:

```
find /users/tom -name "*.pl"
```

But i have troubles to find files, that have one of two different extensions. None of this commands works:

```
find /users/tom -name "*.pl" -name "*.pm"  
find /users/tom -name "*.pl|*.pm"
```

My workaround is to do it one after the other, but I guess there must be a more elegant way.

Now for the file's content:
I know how to print filenames and matching lines with grep:

```
grep * -e "->get(" -e "#hyphenate"
```

This lists all files that contain at least one of the search-strings. But I want a list of files that contain *all* search-strings.

How can this be done? (Form command-line in Ubuntu/Linux)

Comment: I don't get it, why can't `find /usr/tom  | egrep '*.pl| *.pm' ` work?

Comment: @Aftnix: Thanks, this is the solution for part 1 of my question. This gives me the list of all files in which I want to search for some strings. How do I perform this search?

Comment: Not a particularly good solution; a standard wildcard like `find -name '*.p[lm]'` would work better.

Comment: **TL;DR:** `grep -ri 'my string'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` can recursively search directories with `-r`. To only get file names, not the matching lines, use `-l`.

```
grep -rl -- '->get(\|#hyphenate' /users/tom | grep '\.p[lm]$'
```

Or, with find:

```
find /users/tom -name '*.p[lm]' -exec grep -l -- '->get(\|#hyphenate' {} +
```

### Update

The above searches for `->get(` **or** `#hyphenate`, if you want both, you have to run `grep` twice:

```
find /users/tom -name '*.p[lm]' -exec grep -l -- '->get(' {} + \
| xargs grep -l '#hyphenate'
```

If your file names contain whitespace, you might need to specify `-Z` for the first `grep` and `-0` for `xargs`.

Comment: This is not a proper solution; it will list files which contain any match, not all the search expressions.

Comment: @tripleee: You're right. I missunderstood the question.

Comment: @tripleee: should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

`grep -r PLACE_YOUR_STRING_HERE | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep '.p1\|.pm'`

Replace the string with the pattern you are looking for and then run the command after going to the folder in which you wish to look.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /usr/tom | egrep '*.pl| *.pm' | xargs cat | grep <PATTERN>
```

Comment: A lone `*` is strictly speaking a regex error, though most greps will simply skip the erroneous part of the expression. The reason ` *` works is accidental, as it will permit zero repetitions of the erroneous space.

Comment: Also, as ever, the lone `cat` is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html); you can add some flags to the final `grep` to avoid printing the names of matching files; but here, that appears to be the precise opposite of what the OP wants.